# User's TON wallet in telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, ton

How can I implement TON wallets for telegram bot in python? It is necessary that each user has his own balance. I saw an official example of a bot with a balance, but it still does not indicate how exactly to implement the user's balance.

I searched in the official documentation (https://docs.ton.org/develop/dapps/tutorials/accept-payments-in-a-telegram-bot-2). But there, the replenishment of the user's balance occurs through the receipt of transaction data. Getting value and message fields. And the message field is supposed to be the user id in this implementation. Maybe I misunderstood something, so please correct me.